# Disable lint markers in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, when you view code in the editor pane, on the far right where the vertical scrollbar is located, often I see indicators that are color coded to match lint issues. Is it possible to turn this off? If I move the mouse over a lint marker, it pops up an overlay over the code to give details of the issue.  I find this more a nuisance since I rarely fix warning issues. It would be nice if it could only show the red indicators where severe errors are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the **Error stripe mark** checkbox for the severities that you don't want to see in the right gutter under scrollbar:

[image: color scheme | general]

Comment: doesn't this change apply to all errors, and not just lint? ...such as compile errors and other severe things one still might want to be red
I, for one, would like lint errors/warnings to be differentiated from compile errors, etc. I don't see a way in these Color Scheme settings to do that.